# How to use Fabric.js as an imported module from a cdn/script tag?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I need fabric js in my project . For this i'm using cdnjs reference like this :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

and then :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
```

so now i have Global variable canvas . 
How to get rid of this global var and use fabric as an imported module ( preferably ES6 import )

It is important that i cannot use npm manager to install fabric js as an npm module

Comment: 1. How can you tell `canvas` is global? 2. Even if it is, it's only because you're a) defining it at the top level of the browsing context, 2) using `var` to do it instead of, say, `const` or `let`. This has nothing to do with the fact that `fabric` is globally defined

Comment: Maybe including question about canvas as global was incorrect .I should have asked only about importing fabric from cdn and that is all.
But fabric is globally defined . It is Global namespace polluting , isn't it ? Can i awoid it ? Thank you

Comment: I see. Well, even if you manage to import it with some sort of trick, `fabric` will still end up defined globally because of [this](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js#L179).

Comment: That said, I wouldn't be too worried about `fabric` in particular, unless you have some other library conflicting with it. You're right that polluting global scope should as a rule be avoided, but if you're careful about it and only allow trusted 3rd party scripts to do it, this shouldn't be a problem.